# I want to do a select query and a join with two datasets in sparql based ont the Lahman Baseball database

Tags: sparql, jena

I have a query I want to write that looks like this...

```
PREFIX ma: <http://mydataset.com/ns/master#>
PREFIX ap: <http://mydataset.com/ns/appearances#> 
SELECT DISTINCT ?masterID ?nameFirst ?nameLast
WHERE
{
  ap:LAN ap:masterID ?masterID .
  ?masterID ma:nameLast ?nameLast .
  ?masterID ma:nameFirst ?nameFirst .
}
ORDER BY ?nameLast ?nameFirst
```

I am pretty new to sparql and apache jena so forgive my naiveness but I set up my data as shown below...

```
ap:LAN ap:masterID "aasedo01" .
ap:LAN ap:masterID "abreuto01" .
ap:ALT ap:masterID "berrych01" .
ap:ALT ap:masterID "brownji01" .
ap:ALT ap:masterID "carropa01" .
ap:ALT ap:masterID "connojo01" .
ap:ALT ap:masterID "crosscl01" .
...

ma:aasedo01 ma:nameFirst "Don" .
ma:aasedo01 ma:nameLast "Aase" .
ma:abadan01 ma:nameFirst "Andy" .
ma:abadan01 ma:nameLast "Abad" .
ma:abadfe01 ma:nameFirst "Fernando" .
ma:abadfe01 ma:nameLast "Abad" .
ma:abadijo01 ma:nameFirst "John" .
ma:abadijo01 ma:nameLast "Abadie" .
ma:abreuto01 ma:nameFirst "Tony" .
ma:abreuto01 ma:nameLast "Abreu" .
...
```

In the first set of data I have constructed it so it is grouped by team ID and then the ids of the players associated with that team. I then made the other set of data so that it is the id of the player associated with their first name and last name. I want to query for the first name and last name of all the players associated with the team LAN. I feel like I'm close I just don't really quite understand how to join them because currently I get nothing back. The data that I  have above should just return two players Don Aase and Tony Abreu.

Comment: No, in the first "group" of data resp. triples you used a string literal and in the second a URI. For example, `ap:LAN ap:masterID "aasedo01"` - here the object is just the string `"aasedo01"`. a literal has no identity and nothing in common with the URI `ma:aasedo01`. You have to use the URI also in the first triple, i.e. `ap:LAN ap:masterID ma:aasedo01` to have some "connected" triples

Comment: Awesome that is a great catch. I honestly was just following examples online and didn't even know you could have the 3rd part of the triple be a URI so this is great and it worked! so now I can move on to my other queries. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Solution thanks to AKSW was to change my data so that it didn't use a string literal but instead a URI like so... ap:LAN ap:masterID ma:aasedo01